# call javascript from cocoa

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webview

I have a cocoa application which contains a webview. Inside the webview is essentially a table of selectable information. I would like to access a user's selection inside this webview (html/js) from a button click (in the cocoa app). I assume that I could get this information by calling a javascript function inside of the web document, but I'm unsure about how to call this function from the cocoa app. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:your_javascript_here];
```